# Proving a Sobolev-type inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $w := e^{-x^2}$, and $u$ be such that
$$
\| u \|_{1, w} := \|u\|_{w} + |u|_{1,w} := \int_{\mathbb R} ((u(x))^2 + (u'(x))^2) \, w(x) \, dx \leq \infty.
$$
I am trying to understand why
$$
\int_{\mathbb R} x^2 (u(x))^2 \, w(x) \, dx \leq C \, \| u \|_{1, w}.
$$

In the textbook I'm reading (Spectral method, by Shen, Tang and Wang), the proof of this result (Appendix B8) goes as follows:
We start by writing, using integration by parts,
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} x u^2 w \, dx = \int_{\mathbb R} uu'w \, dx \leq \|u\|_{\omega} |u|_{1,\omega},$$
to deduce $xu^2w \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$. Already at this point, why must the boundary terms be $0,$ and why does integrability imply $xu^2 w \to 0$? I can see that we could perform integration by parts on a bounded interval and then let the bounds go to $\infty$, but how do we conclude that the boundary terms, $[u^2 w]^{b}_a$, go to zero?

The rest of the proof consists in using integration by parts again
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} (xu)^2 w dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb R} u^2 w dx + \int_{\mathbb R} x u u' w dx $$
and then Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. Here again, I don't understand exactly how integration by part is applied.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

---

EDIT: @Gio67 recalled below that integrability and continuity alone do not imply convergence to 0 as $|x| \to \infty$, and therefore the proof in the textbook is not strictly speaking correct. Using his method, one can prove that, for suitably chosen $a_n \to -\infty$ and $b_n \to \infty$,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{a_n}^{b_n} x u^2 \, dx = 0,
$$
but it's still not clear how one can go from this to the conclusion that $x u^2$ is integrable. It is possible split the domain into the regions $x \geq 0$ and $x < 0$ and to use monotone convergence,
but this requires to know that $u(0) \leq \infty$.

Comment: I don't understand your notation. Especially the second inequality. You've used norms you haven't defined.

Comment: @almosteverywhere thanks  for pointing this out. I have edited the first equation to define all the norms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx<\infty$, with $f\ge 0$ you can find a sequence $b_n\to\infty$ such that $f(b_n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$, since if not, then $f(x)\ge \epsilon_0>0$ for all $x$ which would give you a contradiction. It is false that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$. It is enough to take the graph of $f$ to be made of triangles of height 1, base $1/n^2$ and centered at each $n$.
So in your case you can find $a_n\to-\infty$ and $b_n\to\infty$ such that
$$((u(b_n))^2 + (u'(b_n))^2) \, w(b_n)\to0$$
and $$((u(a_n))^2 + (u'(a_n))^2) \, w(a_n)\to0.$$
Then you do the integration by parts in $[a_n,b_n]$ to get
$$\int_{a_n}^{b_n} x u^2 w \, dx = \int_{a_n}^{b_n} uu'w \, dx+u^2(b_n)w(b_n)-u^2(a_n)w(a_n)$$
and then you let $n\to \infty$ noting that the integral $\int_{a_n}^{b_n} uu'w \, dx$ converges by the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem. Similar trick for the second integration by parts probably.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes things clearer.

Comment: Just wondering: As is, the dominated convergence theorem cannot be applied to the left-hand side right, because the function can't be dominated. One would therefore have to split the domain in two and use monoton convergence to prove that the integrand in the left-hand side is integrable. Does this sound correct?

Comment: yes on the left-hand side you have to use monotone convergence